# iPhone Dev - Creating a one time UIAlertView like in Temple Run

Tags: iphone, real-time, uialertview

You know how Temple Run sometimes has alerts when you open the App that appear even though you don't update the App? I understand how you would implement this if you were to submit an update to your App, but how does Imangi implement new alerts without releasing new versions of the App? (I'm assuming they upload it from some server, but I'm an amateur at all of that stuff so could someone sorta vaguely explain how I might go about doing that? Will I need to learn Internet programming languages :O?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could host a plist online, with an array of alerts stored as dictionaries, with attributes like 'title', 'body' etc. The app would then parse this and to create an alert. You could then set up a method which searches for updates to this file every time the app opens and has connectivity.

This is not the only way - there are probably hundreds of other files types/ automated systems to use, however this is a simple way, and roughly how all of them work, and I have implemented something like this in some of my apps. Hope this helps, if you wan't any help coding it, I will be happy to help!

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jonathan. I would set a plist with a reference number on your server. and it would look something like this. I'm using concept, not code. It would be as simple as hosting it on your server. Or it could be as complicated as your creating a user interface on your website that allows you to just plug in the information and it would create the plist for you.

```
-(void)checkanddisplaynotificationbasedonupdatedplistontheserver{

  int currentnotificationnumber = userprefs preference for item "notification"

  get and parse notification.plist from your server
  notificationnumber = object at index 0
  if notificationnumber > currentnotificationnumber{
  display your notification with parsed plist
  }
}
```